# compare variable with string bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, case

```
st.txt
```

"failed" "aa" "2018-04-03T17:43:38Z"

```
   while read status name date; do
    case "$status" in
    'aborted')
        echo -1
        ;;
    "failed")
        echo -1
        ;;
    'succeeded')
        echo 0
        ;;
    *)
        echo 0
    esac
    exit 0
done < st.txt
```

But I always get 0 as the output.

Comment: Is there only one line in `st.txt`?

Comment: yes, it is, only one

Comment: What is the contents of `st.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `"failed"` with `"\"failed\""`. It should be:

```
while read status name date; do
    case "$status" in
        'aborted')
            echo -1
            ;;
        "\"failed\"")
            echo -1
            ;;
        'succeeded')
            echo 0
            ;;
        *) echo 0
    esac
    exit 0
done<st.txt
```

Also consider using [`read with -r`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#read_.24foo).

There is also an easier way to do what you want:

```
if [ "$(cut -d ' ' -f1 st.txt)" = "\"failed\"" ]
then
    printf -- "-1\n"
fi
```

Comment: Why is it necessary here to include the quotes in the matching expression? If I understand your solution correctly, this is the same as writing `'"failed"'`, and this in turn would only make sense if there are also quotes around *failed* in `st.txt`. This is unlikely, since *succeeded* and *aborted* also don't have quotes.

Comment: Yes, it would be the same as writing '"failed"'.  You're right that if
OP also checked for `"succeeded"`" or `"aborted"` he would have to escape
double quotes. Additional problem is that OP reads `status`, `name`
and `date` but only uses `status`.

Comment: And I now see that in the edited post, there are indeed double quotes in the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add single quotes around the double-quoted strings:

```
while read status name date; do
    case "$status" in
        '"aborted"')
             echo -1
             ;;
        '"failed"')
             echo -1
             ;;
        '"succeeded"')
             echo 0
             ;;
        *)
             echo 0
    esac
    exit 0
done < st.txt
```